# Retrieving the user who list up the product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

user.rb

```
has_many :places
has_many :orders
has_one :cart

has_many :order_transactions
```

product.rb

```
class Product

has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

lineitem.rb

```
class LineItem

belongs_to :product
belongs_to :cart
belongs_to: order
```

order.rb

```
class Order

belongs_to :user
belongs_to :product
has_many :purchases
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :orders, :through => :order_products
```

Hi guys, I face a problem in retrieving the user who list up the product. As the site I am currently working on allows users to list up products for sale, how am i suppose to credit the earnings to the respective user? I understand that I would have to first retrieve the user who list up the product.

However, I am unable to do so from order controller based on the association I have now.

Appreciate any help out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified the relationship between users and products in your models.

```
User.rb - add:
has_many :products

Product.rb -aa:
belongs_to :user
```

You will also need to be sure the user_id is in the product table, and the product_id is in the user table.